# App not showing in Play Store in some devices

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-play

After publishing my app on the Play Store, I noticed that it is no possible to search for it in some devices, and also on Desktop. It tells me that the app is not compatible.

Although, the min. API I'm using is API 16 (Android 4.1) and the devices I'm testing it in run Android 4.4. *The app however, works just fine in those devices if I install it through USB from Android Studio.*
(I have several other apps that I have published and they do appear in the search results!)

Also I have checked my manifest and the build.gradle of the app, but after comparing it to the other apps' files it doesn't seem like they're the cause of the problem...

Here's my manifest file: https://hastebin.com/jifamoluli.xml

Comment: Post your full manifest.  Most likely its some required feature (or implicitly required feature).

Comment: Ok, I edited the question and added the manifest file.

Answer (score -2):

```
**Please have a look of following i think it will help you.**

First think that could be happen if you provide the minimum api level support it will display only in respective api level of phones but as you mension you have provided api 16 please open your manifest file and check if you have provided the screen support or not if please add below code. 
<supports-screens
 android:smallScreens="true"
 android:normalScreens="true"
 android:largeScreens="true"
 android:xlargeScreens="true" 
 android:anyDensity="true" 
 android:resizeable="true" />
```

Comment: The default for all those things is true.  You only need a supports screens if you want to restrict things.

Comment: if you are still getting problem please post your manifest file

Comment: @GabeSechan where is that information from? Reading the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html), on **largeScreens**, for example, it says: _"The default value for this actually varies between some versions, so it's better if you explicitly declare this attribute at all times."_